# Modifying a PBN file with sed

Tags: sed

(Complete beginner in sed.)

In sed, how do I do the following?

In the below-example .PBN (Portable Bridge Notation) file:

```
[Deal "N:Q5.KT653.AJ.KT52 73.AQJ984.9543.8 AK9.7.Q876.AJ943 JT8642.2.KT2.Q76"]

[Deal "N:KQJ7642.9.QJ8.K8 93.543.T532.A743 A85.QJT.AK96.T92 T.AK8762.74.QJ65"]

[Deal "N:AQJ82.J.QJT85.KQ K954.Q7532.4.652 T3.AT9.AK96.A983 76.K864.732.JT74"]

[Deal "N:AQ4.T65432.AJ4.J 32.87.Q63.KT8765 K98.QJ9.K75.AQ92 JT765.AK.T982.43"]
```

for every other line (i.e., line 2, 4, 6, etc.), I would like to swap the part that starts after `N:` until the space delimiter, with the part that starts with the second space delimiter, and ends with the following space delimiter; and change the `N` to `S`.

(For example, in the second line, `N` becomes `S` (in each line, there will be no other `N`s), and the part `KQJ7642.9.QJ8.K8` replaced with `A85.QJT.AK96.T92`, and `A85.QJT.AK96.T92` replaced with `KQJ7642.9.QJ8.K8`.)

(If it matters, I will be working on [GNU sed live editor](https://sed.js.org/).)

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].